# Notation in Group Theory: Subgroup generated by $x^n$

Tags: group-theory, notation

Okay, this is a silly question but I don't understand a bit of notation in a homework assignment (I prefer self-study over class, and the notation is not used in the book). I tried Google, wolfram alpha and previous threads here but I can't find it.

Let $G$ be group. Let $H$ be a subgroup generated by all elements $x^{21}, x \in G$.

What does this mean? The subgroup generated by all elements of order $21$ and $1$?

Comment: If $G$ were abelian (a very special case), then $\{x^{21} \mid x \in G \}$ would be a subgroup $H$.  However in general we would have $H$ be strictly larger (as a set) than just the 21'st powers of elements in $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all elements in $G$. Raise them to the power $21$. Take the resultant elements and consider the subgroup generated by them.

Comment: Haha yes that makes sense... I read it as ($x^{21}$,x)  $\in$ G.....

Comment: @Scipio Should be read as "all elements x to the 21st power for all x in G" :P